# jquery div resizer like stackoverflow one

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I have a vertical only resizable div in my page. I'd like to put a handle "grip" like what there is in this page at the bottom of the textarea in the section "Your Answer".
How can I do it?

Comment: depends on browser too. Chrome does it always IE onyl if you specifically tell it to via CSS. Search for "TextBox Resize CSS" in SO or your favourite search engine...

Answer (score 3):

How about [jQuery UI's resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) interaction?

```
$('some-selector').resizable({
    handles: 's',
    maxWidth: 300,
    minWidth: 300
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/6H4Nc/

Comment: You said "div" and you said "horizontal only." Is it a div or a textarea, and is it horizontally resizable, or vertically resizable?

Comment: No grip is showed. However I'd like to have the same style as the stackoverflow one :P

Comment: @Matt. Yes i was mistaken. I'd want to say "vertical". Anyway, like there is in this page.

Comment: Ok, then it's just a matter of CSS. Use Firebug or Chrome/Safari's dev tools to peek at how SO implements it.

Comment: Thank you. I was using IE one but no succeed.

Comment: See the updated demo. You can get the look you want by tweaking the CSS of the `.ui-resizable-handle`.

Comment: Note, I added all of 4 lines of CSS to get that look.

Comment: Yes, now only the grip lines are missing. Thank you. Can you give me some indications to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The textarea comes with that functionality, but you could look into [jQuery UI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/)